# Usage of Google People API with GoogleApiClient (list all friends)

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-people-api

```
// Setup
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScopes(new Scope(PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY))
    .build();

mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();

// Login
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleClient);
mActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN);

// Restore Login
// mGoogleClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
```

This is how I handle the login result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data)
{
    if (mGoogleClient != null && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN)
    {
        mLoginResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (mLoginResult.isSuccess())
        {
            getAllContacts();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the problem, how can I convert this old cold? I want to keep using the `GoogleApiClient`.

```
private void getAllContacts()
{
    // 1) Own Profil
    Person pMe = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleClient);

    // 2) Friends
    PendingResult<People.LoadPeopleResult> result = Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleClient, People.OrderBy.BEST, null);
    People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult = result.await();
    if (loadPeopleResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
    {
        PersonBuffer people = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer();
        for (Person p : people)
        {
            // ...
        }
        people.close();
    }
}
```

**What I want**

I want to list all people someone is following (or alternatively someone has in any of his circles) with the help of `GoogleApiClient`. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You do realize that this will only return the people that the current user has added to https://contacts.google.com.   It does not return people they have emailed with or are following on Google+

Comment: This won't work at all now (since a few months). What I want is list all people that someone is following, do you know how this works with the help of `GoogleApiClient`?

Comment: That's my point.  You cant there is no api that will show you who a user is following on Google+.

Comment: I did not know that... The deprecated `Plus.API` could do that though I think...

Comment: Alternatively listing people in a circle would help me as well. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: There is no way to see who anyone is following or who they have added to a circle.  Or what circles ore communities they are part of.

Comment: But the contacts.google.com does contain your circles as well. Do you know how to list all my contacts from contacts.google.com with the `GoogleApiClient`? Then I could check if can do something with that

Comment: Yes the Google Contacts website has access to who is in your circles.  However if you use try me at the bottom of the page you will notice that the API only returns the people that you personally added.   Google has access to the data and uses it on the website.  They do not give developers access to the data as part of the APIs.

Comment: I've seen that now, thanks. Still, I wonder if I can use `GoogleApiClient` for the people API as I can add the scope to it but I don't know to go on form there